# Manually define schema using gatsby-transformer-json

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am have two existing JSON files, one containing location information and the other post information, with location and post IDs joining them:

`locations.json`:

```
[
  {
    "locationId": "location-id-1",
    "name": "name-2",
    "posts": ["post-id-1", "post-id-2"]
  },
  {
    "locationId": "location-id-2",
    "name": "name-2",
    "posts": ["post-id-3", "post-id-4", "post-id-5"]
  },
  // ...
]
```

`posts.js`:

```
[
  {
    "postId": "post-id-1",
    "title": "some-title-1",
    "locationId": "location-id-1",
    "text": "..."
  },
  {
    "postId": "post-id-2",
    "title": "some-title-2",
    "locationId": "location-id-1",
    "text": "..."
  },
  // ...
]
```

I am using [`gatsby-transformer-json`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-json/) which allows me to create GraphQL queries using `allLocationsJson` and `allPostsJson`. However, I don't know how to alter the GraphQL schema to allow for queries like this:

```
{
  allLocationsJson {
    edges {
      node {
        locationId
        name
        posts {
          postId
          title
          text
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem comes with the `posts` field because GraphQL doesn't realize I want `posts` to be a list of post objects, not just post IDs. Is there any way for me to accomplish this kind of query with my existing JSON structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatsby treats special fields ending with `___NODE`. When Gatsby creates the schema for these fields, it turns them into links to other types. So if you rename the `posts` field on locations.json to `posts___NODE` then you'll be able to query the data as you want.